# How to store multiple checkbox values in multiple columns of same table in database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

In below code, I am selecting 4 checkboxes and I am able to display those 4 selected checkboxes. But how to store those 4 selected checkbox values in different columns under lecture1, lecture2 and so on in same table of my database. 4 is default value for checkbox of lectures.

```
$teachername1=$_POST[ 'teachername1' ];
echo"$teachername1";
$_SESSION['teachername1']=$_POST[ 'teachername1' ];
if(!empty($_POST['lecture']))
{
   $checked_count = count($_POST['lecture']);
   echo"You have selected following ".$checked_count."option(s):<br/>";
   foreach($_POST['lecture'] as $selected)
   {
      echo $selected."<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you're after the psychic forum. Here, we prefer to see the structure of tables rather than trying to imagine them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to store Checkbox Values in MySQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784533/whats-the-best-way-to-store-checkbox-values-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted the table structure but anyways I will try to give my best suggestions here.

**Existing System:**

You have 4 choice columns in your tables for eg:

Make all 4 columns as boolean to check whether they are set(1) or not set(0) by inserting 1 or 0 respectively to keep track whether they have selected the choice or not.

```
id,(other columns),choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4
```

Make sure whenever you insert the check box selected values while inserting into database table set 1 or 0 to the respective tables.

When you fetch the records for the respective row if the column is set to 1 then that checkbox was selected.

There is problem with the system what you have. Please use the following way.

**Suggested Way:**

Please don't store the checkbox values in different columns. Today you may have only 4 values. Think in future you may come up with 8 checkboxes. In that case you need to add 4 more columns.

Instead of that you can normalize your database table by having one more table with respective name. Now your new normalized table looks like

```
checkbox table
--------------

id, checkbox_name, checkbox_value(if any)

teachers table
--------------

id, cols (other columns which I dont know whether its there or not)

teachers_choices //This is the checkbox selected table
----------------

id, teacher_id(this references to teacher table), checkbox_id (this references to checkbox table)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion:)