# How to insert multiple choice in one column on PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Here what I wanted

[image]

So on this picture is based on one column database
how do I insert this to a database?
So it'll be like this
ex:
hotel=[1 star, 2 starm,3 star]

```
 <label>Kelas hotel*</label>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="KELAS_HOTEL_REQP[]" value="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="KELAS_HOTEL_REQP[]" value="2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1"><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="KELAS_HOTEL_REQP[]" value="3">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="KELAS_HOTEL_REQP[]" value="4">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="KELAS_HOTEL_REQP[]" value="5">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">
        <i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
        </div>
```

This is the insert query

```
{
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$y = date('y');
$m = date('m');
$d = date('d');
$h = date('H');
$i = date('i');
$s = date('s');
$status = '';
$ID_REQP = "REQP".$y.$m.$d.$h.$i.$s;
// Ambil Data yang Dikirim dari Form
$TUJUAN_REQP = $_POST['TUJUAN_REQP'];
$TANGGAL_BERANGKAT_REQP = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['TANGGAL_BERANGKAT_REQP']));
$DURASI_REQP =$_POST['DURASI_REQP'];
$JML_PESERTA_REQP = $_POST['JML_PESERTA_REQP'];
$TIPE_PERMINTAAN_REQP = $_POST['TIPE_PERMINTAAN_REQP'];
$HARGA_MIN_REQP = $_POST['HARGA_MIN_REQP'];
$HARGA_MAX_REQP = $_POST['HARGA_MAX_REQP'];
$KELAS_HOTEL_REQP = $_POST['KELAS_HOTEL_REQP'];
$TRANSPORT_REQP = $_POST['TRANSPORT_REQP'];
$TRANSPORT_NAMA_REQP = $_POST['TRANSPORT_NAMA_REQP'];
$NAMA_PENGHUBUNG_REQP = $_POST['NAMA_PENGHUBUNG_REQP'];
$EMAIL_PENGHUBUNG_REQP = $_POST['EMAIL_PENGHUBUNG_REQP'];
$NOMOR_WA_REQP = $_POST['NOMOR_WA_REQP'];
$PERMINTAAN_KHUSUS_REQP = $_POST['PERMINTAAN_KHUSUS_REQP'];
$TENGGAT_WAKTU_REQP = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['TENGGAT_WAKTU_REQP']));
      $sql1 = "INSERT INTO request_pelanggan(ID_REQP, TUJUAN_REQP, TANGGAL_BERANGKAT_REQP, DURASI_REQP, JML_PESERTA_REQP, TIPE_PERMINTAAN_REQP, HARGA_MIN_REQP, HARGA_MAX_REQP, KELAS_HOTEL_REQP, TRANSPORT_REQP, TRANSPORT_NAMA_REQP, NAMA_PENGHUBUNG_REQP, EMAIL_PENGHUBUNG_REQP, NOMOR_WA_REQP, PERMINTAAN_KHUSUS_REQP, TENGGAT_WAKTU_REQP) VALUES ('".$ID_REQP."','".$TUJUAN_REQP."','".$TANGGAL_BERANGKAT_REQP."','".$DURASI_REQP."','".$JML_PESERTA_REQP."','".$TIPE_PERMINTAAN_REQP."','".$HARGA_MIN_REQP."','".$HARGA_MAX_REQP."','".$KELAS_HOTEL_REQP."','".$TRANSPORT_REQP."','".$TRANSPORT_NAMA_REQP."','".$NAMA_PENGHUBUNG_REQP."','".$EMAIL_PENGHUBUNG_REQP."','".$NOMOR_WA_REQP."','".$PERMINTAAN_KHUSUS_REQP."','".$TENGGAT_WAKTU_REQP."')";
      $sql2= mysqli_query($connect, $sql1) or die('Gagal menyimpan paket');
     if($sql2){ // Cek jika proses simpan ke database sukses atau tidak
         $status = 'sukses';
         header("location: ../index.php?status=$status");
      }
      else{
        // Jika Gagal, Lakukan :
        echo "Maaf, Terjadi kesalahan saat mencoba untuk menyimpan data ke database.";
        echo "<br><a href='umroh_upload.php'>Kembali Ke Form</a>";
      }
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035773/how-to-add-multiple-checkbox-selections-to-my-database-using-php/66037472#66037472

Comment: Quick question...how can the hotel be 2 star, 3 star and 4 star all at the same time? That doesn't appear to make sense. Are you sure these shouldn't be radio buttons, which allow only one option to be chosen from all of the available choices?

Comment: Anyway, you should not store multiple values in one column. That denormalises your data and makes it more difficult to work with. Learn how to design your schema correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple checkbox selections to my database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035773/how-to-add-multiple-checkbox-selections-to-my-database-using-php)