# How to pass the dynamic text box value to another php page

Tags: php, javascript

i make a dynamic textbox through javascript now i want to post the data of all dynamically generated textboxes to php script and then insert into a table. how can i do this...

```
> var intTextBox=0;
> 
> //FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT 
> function addElement() { 
> intTextBox = intTextBox+1;
> 
> var contentID = document.getElementById('content'); 
> var newTBDiv =document.createElement('div');
> newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox); 
> newTBDiv.innerHTML="Author  : <input type='text' id='citingfield' name='"intTextBox"'/>";
> contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
> }
> 
> //FUNCTION TO REMOVE TEXT BOX ELEMENT 
> function removeElement() {
> if(intTextBox != 0) 
> {
> var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
> contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText'+intTextBox));
> intTextBox = intTextBox-1; } }
> 
> <body>
> 
> <form action="add_save.php" method="post"  > 
> 
> <div id="content"></div> <p><a href="javascript:addElement();"
> >Add</a> <a href="javascript:removeElement();" >Remove</a></p>
> 
> <input name="submit" type="submit" id=" " value="Submit">
> </from>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get value of this textbox using `$_POST['intTextBox']` , and use it to `insert` into `table`

Answer (score 0):

Just use POST Method ,you will get all the filled values in another page

```
--- index.php---    
    <form method="POST" action="destination.php">
    your code here. Dynamically created code will append to here
    </form>

 -----destination.php---

    print_r($_POST)
```

Comment: you have to mention action attribute in form tag, please correct it

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_POST arrays.
By using the same name with brackets.
You can check this post : 
[Submitting a multidimensional array via POST with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your javascript for any textbox you wanna add dynamically

```
      var box=document.createElement("input");
      box.setAttribute("type","text");
      box.setAttribute("name","box1");
      box.setAttribute("value","someNewValue");
      content.appendChild(box);
```

then after submision in your add_save.php do this

```
 $boxValue=$_REQUEST['box1'];

 <tr><?=$boxValue ?></tr>
```