# How to create a for each PHP loop to set variables from table data

Tags: php, forms

Total beginner with PHP:

I have an form based on table data that the user can add any number of rows too, currently I'm calling the data in my .php like:

```
$para01 = $_POST["1_0"];
$url01 = $_POST["1_1"];
$para02 = $_POST["2_0"];
$url02 = $_POST["2_1"];
```

etc.

I'd like a way call the table data, so I can cater for x amount of rows

So, my pseudo code would be:

- for each row, apply cell id 0 to $url and id 1 to $para
- then echo url and para in some html
- repeat until all rows have been expressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use arrays! 
a simple way to do it would be to call all post variables, and then sort them with php...

I did it for you really quick, assuming the form input fields look like:

formstart
url1
para1
url2
para2
url3
para3
and so on...

submit
endform

```
$i=1;
$urls = array();
$paras = array();
foreach($_POST as $variable){
    if($i==1){
        array_push($urls,$variable);
        $i++;
    }else{
        array_push($paras,$variable);
        $i=1;
    }
}
echo'<table><tr><td>';
foreach($urls as $url){
    echo $url.'<br />';
}
echo'</td><td>';
foreach($paras as $para){
    echo $para.'<br />';
}
echo'</td></tr></table>';
```

Edit

You would pair them like this...

```
 $_POST = array('url1','paragraph1','url2','paragraph2','url3','paragraph3');
$urls = array();
$paras = array();
$i=1;
$c=0;
foreach($_POST as $variable){
    if($i==1){
        array_push($urls,$variable);
        $i++;
    }else{
        array_push($paras,$variable);
        $i=1;
     $c++;
    }
}

echo'<table>';
for($x=0;$x<$c;$x++){
   echo'<tr><td>'.$urls[$x].'</td><td>'.$paras[$x].'</td></tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: thanks for this- I have it working, but how would I get the para in the first foreach loop, instead of separate to it? Each indexed url and para needs to be paired in the loop.

Comment: I editted the above... Now you can pair them with the row, you can even give the td an id... like, 

<tr><td id="left'.$i.'"></td><td id="right'.$i.'"></td></tr>

Comment: thanks for the edit- but doesn't seem to work for me? Does the else need a } infront of it? I added it, but I got another parser error on ; line 20?

Comment: Yes!haha, sorry about that! yes, the else needs a closing bracket before it.

Comment: I really should check my code before i send it, i just wrote it really quick so you could get the idea.  let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Hey Nickolas, I've just noticed a funny thing- the result of the above paired example seem to loop twice- once with all the variables/arrays and then a second time with empty fields. So three sets of urls and paras produces 6 <tr></tr>, 3 with the correct data in order and then 3 empty. Also, any PHP that I echo inside the FOR function is duplicated as well, a basic preg_replace gives me two copies of an reg url so my links read src="hello.jpghello.jpg". Any idea why? Perhaps something to do with the FOR conditions?

Comment: Images no longer duplicating- that was something I messed up. Other stuff (double loop) still stands.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php this solves all my problems!

Comment: Ok, sorry about the confusion, I think the problem there was that I put the $c++ in the worng place.  The edit above works, try it as is first, then get rid of the $_POST array at the top so you can utilize your form post instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should make the url and the para a (two) dimensional array. Then, loop through the _POST[] variable, with a two dimensional for loop. Add the values to the array, and print them if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can use it as arrays. That is like,

```
<input type="text" name="para[]" />
<input type="text" name="url[]" />

<input type="text" name="para[]" />
<input type="text" name="url[]" />

<input type="text" name="para[]" />
<input type="text" name="url[]" />
```

And in php, you can use like

```
<?php
foreach($_POST[para] as $key=>$val)
{
}

foreach($_POST[url] as $key=>$val)
{
}
?>
```