# Form Validation required at Client side? Or if same done at Server side is enough?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, wordpress

I'm building a website based on wordpress and I put there a form which uses jQuery.
However, I'm starting to understand jquery just now, so i am not feeling very well while working with it yet. I have two questions.

**First One:**
Regarding this form, is it necessary to validade the form at both client and server side? Or only at server-side (php) is enough?

**Second Question:**
The form have some fields, which can be duplicated if I click on a button. For this, I'm using the following code:

Jquery Code:

```
(function($){

 $countForms = 1;

      $.fn.addForms = function(idform){

                    var myform = "<table>"+
                     "  <tr>"+
                     "     <td>Field A ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                     "     <td><input type='text' name='fielda["+$countForms+"]'></td>"+
                     "     <td>Field B ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                     "     <td><textarea name='fieldb["+$countForms+"]'></textarea></td>"+
                     "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                     "  </tr>"+
                     "</table>";



                    if(idform=='mybutton'){
                        alert(idform);
                        myform = $("<div>"+myform+"</div>");
                        $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
                        $(this).append(myform);
                        $countForms++;
                    }

      };
})(jQuery);         



$(function(){
    $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var idform=this.id;

        if($countForms<3){
            $("#container").addForms(idform);
        }       
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="container"><div>
<form method="post" name="b" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Field A</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='dadoA'></td>
        <td>Field B</td>
        <td><textarea name="dadoB"></textarea></td>
        <td><button>remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<button id="mybutton">add form</button>

<div align="center">
<p><input type="submit" value="Registar" name="registar"></p>
</div>
```

I know how to use php to validate these fields. What I don't know is how to validate when I duplicate them.
I mean, I have this form with 2 fields, I duplicate them and suppose user fills this new (third) field with a wrong/unaccepted value.
After clicking "Submit", how can I use PHP to validate input, refresh the page, echo the 2 original fields and the duplicate ones(which user duplicated), all with their respective inputs filled by user and with the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, from a UX perspective you should try to validate client-side and then double check that server side. It's pretty annoying to submit a form only to find out there's something wrong. Showing errors / problems prior to submit is always a plus.

Comment: So you suggest jquery plus php is that it?

Comment: I was going to answer, but this one is just about exactly what I was going to say.  Validation isn't necessarily required.  But, I don't believe it to be sane to process form data without server side validation.  Client side validation should only be used to improve the user experience.

Comment: Yes, jquery will do. I've used this plugin a few times. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ I'm sure there are others. Sounds like you have the PHP aspect covered so I won't address that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Now i'm having a problem with php validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441981/jquery-function-conflicts-with-php-form (if you could hand me a help i would appreciate)
after that i will think about jquery validation.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but you can simplify validation by using this: [Live Validation](http://livevalidation.com/)

This is a javascript validation script. I like it, its lite, fast, and is pretty easy to use. There is full documentation on how to use it and it is all run client side.

Comment: I will take a look and tell something later here then :P

Comment: how do you validate to reject numbers in this live validation? I can't do it right :/

Answer (score 0):

I feel the first question is answered well in [Chief Alchemist's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438458/816584).  To answer the second question, your form with variable fields should post as an array.  When you process and validate the form data you should iterate over each array entry.

Comment: ok, then i guess i will try to validate with php first, the dificult part will be mantain the arrays, then i will think about client side, will take a look at live validation for that.

Comment: can you give me a link to show how to treat the array in the $_Post?
normally i would use: $name = $_POST['name'];
but with an array ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php answers a question about submitting a form as an array and processing it.

Comment: Thank you, atually yesterday looking for an answer myself i found that post. Anyway, now i'm with a bigger problem that i can't find an answer on the internet neither here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441981/jquery-function-conflicts-with-php-form
My $_POST doesn't caught the values of the inputs generated by jquery. Can you give me a help please? I can't move on because of this i'm going crazy.

Comment: wrong link, it was this one i wanted to refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449890/retrieve-data-from-jquery-to-php-before-refresh