# Retrieve data from jquery to php before refresh

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

how can i retrieve the data from the inputs generated by jquery to treat them with php $_POST?

```
(function($){

         $countForms = 1;

              $.fn.addForms = function(idform){

                            var myform = "<table>"+
                             "  <tr>"+
                             "     <td>Field A ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                             "     <td><input type='text' name='field["+$countForms+"][a]'></td>"+
                             "     <td>Field B ("+$countForms+"):</td>"+
                             "     <td><textarea name='field["+$countForms+"][b]'></textarea></td>"+
                             "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
                             "  </tr>"+
                             "</table>";



                            if(idform=='mybutton'){

                                myform = $("<div>"+myform+"</div>");
                                $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
                                $(this).append(myform);
                                $countForms++;
                            }

              };
        })(jQuery);         



        $(function(){
            $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var idform=this.id;

                if($countForms<3){
                    $("#container").addForms(idform);
                }       
            });
        });
```

html/php code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['field'] ) )
{
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ( $_POST['field'] as $diam )
    {
        // here you have access to $diam['top'] and $diam['bottom']
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '  <td>', $diam['a'], '</td>';
        echo '  <td>', $diam['b'], '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    }

?>

<body>

<div>
<form method="post" name="b" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Field A</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='field[0][a]'></td>
        <td>Field B</td>
        <td><textarea name="field[0][b]"></textarea></td>
        <td><button>remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="mybutton">add form</button>

<div align="center">
<p><input type="submit" value="Registar" name="registar"></p>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm not being able to retrieve the data from the duplicated inputs that jquery generates after loading the page. i know that because the foreach just echo the values of the inputs present in the html part. Any suggestions how i can obtain the values of the jquery inputs to treat them with php?

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's actually being sent?

Comment: I used var_dump($diam['a']); var_dump($diam['b']); inside the foreach but it just prints the content of the inputs present in the html part, nothing comes from the ones in the jquery :/

Comment: basic debugging: don't look for what you expect to see - look for what you really ARE getting. dump out the whole $_POST array. If your fields aren't in there anywhere, then your JS code isn't generating/inserting the form fields properly.

Comment: i don't use much var_dump, can you give me a help on how to dump the whole array please?

Comment: use it exactly like I posted it above. http://php.net/var_dump

Comment: i insert "aaa" and "bbb" on the inputs of the html, and "ccc", "ddd" on the generated inputs of jquery.

The result:
array(2) { ["field"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(3) "aaa" ["b"]=> string(3) "bbb" } } ["registar"]=> string(8) "Registar" }

No sign from the inputs of jquery :/

Comment: Then use a dom inspector in your browser to see what's happening before/after your JS code fires. PHP can only process what it receives, so obviously your js/html isn't working right.

Comment: i installed dom inspector on firefox, but now i'm a little confusing using this, i mean, what should i inspect :/