# Append multiple values to a single parameter in html form using different id-s

Tags: html, forms, parameters, radio-button, html-table

I have similar problem to this one:

[How to append multiple values to a single parameter in html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830276/how-to-append-multiple-values-to-a-single-parameter-in-html-form)

The code will be:

**Edit 2 >>**

```
<form action="process.php">
    <input id="id1" type="text" name="id1" value="id1"> 
    <input id="id2" type="text" name="id2" value="id2"> 
    <input id="id3" type="text" name="id3" value="id3"> 
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**<< Edit 2**

The user will be filling several inputs in one form. I would like to get the result in aggregating list. Or in several list if possible like this:

```
parameter[textfields[textfield1:"a",textfield2:"b"], numbers: number_input1:2,number_input2:3, options:[option1:on]..
```

The only difference is that I need is the unique identifier:

- using this answer the parameter list is

  parameter [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
- I need this result

  parameter [**id1** : 1, **id2** : 2, **id3** : 3, **id4** : 4, **id5** : 5]

**Edit 3**

Let say that this is the table and the inputs. With this code:
...

```
<td class=" ">13</td>
        <td class=" "><div class="btn-row">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default active">
                    <input name="130" id="option1" type="radio"> N/A
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input name="t113" id="option2" type="radio"> A
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input name="t213" id="option3" type="radio"> B
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input name="t313" id="option3" type="radio"> C
                </label>
            </div>
        </div></td>
```

...

After the submit I want to have this information:

selected[option1: A, option2 : B, option5 : C] or

selected[C: 1, B : 2, C : 5]

Thanx!

[image: Table look]

Comment: What unique ID. That question you linked to has no ids at all. Please share *your* code too, what you tried, and what the exact issue is that you can't solve.

Comment: Where those numbers (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`) comes from?!

Comment: they will be inputs from the user