# Splitting variables from $_POST

Tags: php

I wanted to split my variables from a form, and enter them into a Mysql Database one by one.
My table 4 fields would be: UserID, Status, HowLate, PassFail
In this example below the UserID would be 75 and 76, but can be any # from the user id in the future.   I am confused on how I would be able to insert these dynamic variables into the database since I don't know what they will be each time.  The only static pattern I have is when I loop through foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) any help

```
$results = print_r($_POST, true);
```

sample data from form

```
75=PRESENT

d75=on time

cc75=passed


76=LATE

d76=10 minutes

cc76=failed
```

I would want to write a query like:

```
insert into attendance (UserID, Status, HowLate, PassFail) values (76, 'Late', '10 minutes', 'failed')
```

also think of this as students in a class, so there is 20 records coming back at once

Comment: You would grab the names of each individual <input> and then insert them into the database. Where are you getting the UserID from? Do you have it in the SESSION?

Comment: huh? I am looking for help here with the php to dynamically figure out  how to write the insert statement with form variables that are always changing

Comment: Why would your query change?

Comment: you need to show us how you are filling your post array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason you're doing this is because you're unaware that you can send multidimensional arrays in HTML forms. I suggest an approach such as.

```
<input name="users[1][userid]" />
<input name="users[1][status]" />
<input name="users[1][howlate]" />
<input name="users[1][passfail]" />

<input name="users[2][userid]" />
<input name="users[2][status]" />
<input name="users[2][howlate]" />
<input name="users[2][passfail]" />
```

Then in php you can access them in the following manner.

```
foreach( $_POST['users'] as $key => $user )
{
    $userID = $user['userid'];  // same for the other fields. 
}
```

Comment: Also, perhaps some searching might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Assign your variables (if you are not using PDO, which you should to avoid SQL injection) for example:

```
$userId = $_POST['userId']; // assuming that is what your field id is from the html form
$status = $_POST['status'];
```

etc.

Then insert into the database table:

```
insert into attendance (UserID, Status, HowLate, PassFail) values ($userId, '$status' etc.
```