# how to build loop to insert array in a table

Tags: sql, arrays

i have the following code:

```
 $var1="bmx"
 $newdata = implode(",", $dx);
 $queryinsert = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ($var1,$newdata)";
```

but with this code i get some like

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (bmx,black,white, green, yellow,grey)";
```

and i need to create a new row for each color, like

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (bmx,white)";
INSERT INTO table VALUES (bmx,black)";etc...
```

i think i should use a foreach but i don't know how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077724/inserting-multiple-rows-from-a-php-form-into-the-database

Comment: i'm sorry still very confusing for me... i'm not very familiar with this type of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this.
Go to the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), you will find everithing there.

```
$var1="bmx"

foreach ($dx as &$value) {
   $queryinsert = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ($var1,&$value)";
}
```