# Inserting the data get from form in array form php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Continue from this topic
[(php) How can put button to get new inputing field (picture inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233283/php-how-can-put-button-to-get-new-inputing-field-picture-inside).

Now I'm wondering how to get the data and insert it into my database

This is the code I use for the form page

```
<b><u> Education </u></b>
<form method="post" action="Resume_data_form_2_confirm.php">
    <div id="main_wrap">
        <div id="clone">
            <br>Education Level : 
            <select name="education[]">
                <option value="bachelor" selected="selected">Bachelor Degree</option>
                <option value="master">Master Degree</option>
                <option value="doctor">Doctoral Degree</option>
            </select>
            Major : <input type="text" name="edu_major[]" placeholder=''>
            Faculty : <input type="text" name="edu_faculty[]" placeholder=''>
            <br>
            <br>
            University : <input type="text" name="edu_university[]" placeholder=''>
            Education Hounour : 
            <select name="edu_honour[]">
                <option value="none" selected="selected">None</option>
                <option value="cum_laude">Cum Laude</option>
                <option value="magna">Magna Cum Laude</option>
                <option value="summa">Summa Cum Laude</option>
            </select>
            Graduated Year : 
            <select name="year[]">
                <?php 
                    $curYear = getdate();
                    for($year = 1990 ; $year <= $curYear['year']; $year++){
                ?>
                <OPTION value = '<?php echo $year;?>'> <?php echo $year;?> </OPTION> 
                <?php
                    }   
                ?>
            </select>         
        </div>

        <div style="float:right;">
            <input type="button" value="+" id="more" style="float:right;"> 
        </div>           
        <br>
        <br>

        <div style="float:right;">
            <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm"  style="float:right;">
        </div>          
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I have a clone function within the code. The question I have is: how can I insert this data into my database.

**Example**
[image]

Suppose that Username is "Test" and Education_ID is auto-incremented, after I click on the "Confirm" button it should be stored in my database like this:

```
Education_ID(1)  Username(2)  Edu_Level(3)   Edu_Major(4)  Edu_Faculty(5)            Edu_University(6)        Edu_Honour(7)  Edu_Graduated_Year(8).

00001(1)         Test(2)      bachelor(3)    IT(4)         Computer Science(5)       Cambridge University(6)  cum_laude(7)   2008(8)
00002(1)         Test(2)      master(3)      IT(4)         Science and Technology(5) University of London(6)  none(7)        2011(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're posting into Resume_data_form_2_confirm.php. Thus, the data will be sent to that PHP file. From there, you can grab the data that you submitted, make a connection with the database, write an insertion query for the data, and then execute the query. I apologize that this is a very high level explanation, but you should be able to find more code specific details on the web for each step that I have stated. Good luck!

Comment: yep that one is the page that contains mysql operations. but it not working for now... i think because the array thing