# Dynamic textfields in javascript and get values through $_POST in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a java script code like below explained, I need to sort out my problems.
i have a data base in which i store question in one table and then store their options in another table, i need the id of the correct answer from question option table to store that id in question table as  answer

```
var template = '';
var count = 1;
function addTextField()
{
    template += "<input type='text' id='option_"+count+"' name='name1[]'>";
    template += "<input type='radio' id='option_"+count+"' name='answer')>";
    document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = template;
    count++;
}

function getId()
{
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('answer');
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        var id=radios[i].id;
        document.write(id);
        //var name = document.getElementsById('id');
        //document.write(name);
            // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my php code:

```php
foreach ($names as $value)
{
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO question_options (options,question_id)
    values('$value','$qid')");
}
```

how can i get the id of selected radio text fields?

i need to store the text fileds value in one table and then the id of that row in another table.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `$_POST` arrays might solve your problem.

Check this answer :

[Submitting a multidimensional array via POST with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php)