# get submitted values with PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom, submit

I want to get the values that belong to the answers of a test.
There could be any number of questions.
A question has the HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='calificar.php'>

<div class='pruebaAlumno'>

    <h5>Pregunta 3</h5>
    <h3>¿Que factores definen la capacidad de una persona?</h3>

    <input type='checkbox' name='respuestaAlumno[]' 
                      value='Voluntad'> Voluntad <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='respuestaAlumno[]' 
                      value='Cultura'> Cultura <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='respuestaAlumno[]' 
                      value='Hábitos'> Hábitos <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='respuestaAlumno[]' 
                      value='Habilidad'> Habilidad <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='respuestaAlumno[]' 
                      value='Perfil'> Perfil <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='respuestaAlumno[]' 
                      value='Dones'> Dones <br>

    <input type='hidden' name='idPregunta' value='41'>
    <input type='hidden' name='tipo' value='C'>
             </fieldset>

            </div>  <div class='calificar'>
                    <input type='submit' name='calificar' value='enviar' >
                </div>
            </form>
```

I want to get

1. Answer (respuestaAlumno)
2. questionID (idPregunta)
3. type (tipo)

from each question.

Then I want to save the data in an array.

A test can have as many questions as the teacher wants. The form has one submit button.

I´ve tried to get the data in different ways. Using JS DOM. Using POST.
I´ve found some PHP DOM tutorials but them all teach how to modify an static HTML.
Please help me to get the submitted data from each fieldset. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format your form names like this.

First question

```
name="respuestaAlumno[0][]"
name="respuestaAlumno[0][]"
...
name="idPregunta[0]"
name="tipo[0]"
```

Second question

```
name="respuestaAlumno[1][]"
name="respuestaAlumno[1][]"
...
name="idPregunta[1]"
name="tipo[1]"
```

You would end up with three arrays in your `$_POST`.

Comment: It worked for me. I also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php
DOM was not necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['calificar'])
 {

 $respuestaAlumno=$_POST['respuestaAlumno'];
 //you need respuestaAlumno array to single string
 echo $data_to_string=implode(",",$respuestaAlumno);
 $count_of_respuestaAlumno=count($_POST['respuestaAlumno']);
 for($i=0;$i<=$count_of_respuestaAlumno-1;$i++)
 {
 echo $data=$respuestaAlumno[$i]."/n";
 }
 //question id
echo  $idPregunta=$_POST['idPregunta'];
 echo $tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
 //do something 
 }
```