# Silverstripe 3.2: How to add and update Dataobjects in a frontend form dynamically?

Tags: jquery, forms, silverstripe, data-objects

Example: I have Members (who can login and update their data) who have one or many qualifications. So I have a DataObject 'Members' and a DataObject 'Qualification' with a has_one/has_many relationship.

Something like this:

```
class Qualification extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array (
        'Title' => 'Text',
        'From' => 'Date',
        'Till' => 'Date'
    );

    private static $has_one = array (
        'Member' => 'Member',
    );
```

...

```
class Member extends DataObject {

   ...

   private static $has_many = array (
      'Qualifications' => 'Qualification',
  );

...
```

Now I want to build a form in the frontend which allows the member to add many qualifications at once and also update existing qualifications in the same form.

It could look like this

> **Qualifikation One**
>
> Title: xxx (textfield)     From: xxx (datefield)      Till: xxx
>   (datefield)
>
> **Qualifikation Two**
>
> Title: xxx (textfield)     From: xxx (datefield)      Till: xxx
>   (datefield)
>
> **+ add qualifications**

What is the best way to do that?

I could use jQuery to add fields dynamically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nzYAW/

But how can I handle to update and add them to the database. Everything I tried was really complicated and messy, so I think maybe somebody else has an idea I just don't see at the moment. Every help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have never done this before, but I would look at trying to use a `GridField` on the front end with the [GridField extensions module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) `GridFieldEditableColumns` and `GridFieldAddNewInlineButton` components.

Comment: @iraia you just need an action that reads the post and change the input attribute name to a format that can be read as an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php . Then just save the "keys" data to the dataobject.

Of course you could have a hidden field that submits the count of the inputs you have, and then concatenate that and get a field, but this way you can just iterate the submitted data quite   easily.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will give both options a try and will report my results here. :)

Comment: Ok. I started with the GridField extension module and it was so easy and worked as expected that I just keep that way. Nevertheless thank you both of you!

Comment: @iraia could you submit your own solution as an answer. Or at least the important bits :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with the solution of 3dgoo. I use a GridField in my frontend form with the [GridField extension module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) and the components `GridFieldEditableColumns` and `GridFieldAddNewInlineButton`. Here is an example:

```
public function MyForm() {

     $config = GridFieldConfig::create();
     $config->addComponent(new GridFieldButtonRow('before'));
     $config->addComponent(new GridFieldEditableColumns());
     $config->addComponent(new GridFieldAddNewInlineButton());
     $gridField = GridField::create('Qualifications', 'Qualifications', Qualification::get()->filter(array('MemberID' => Member::currentUserID()))),$config);

     $fields = new FieldList(

          .... here goes some other Fields like Textfields ...

          TextField::create('MyTextField'),
          CheckboxField::create('MyCheckboxField'),
          $gridField,
     );


     $actions = new FieldList(
          FormAction::create('myAction','save'),
          FormAction::create('myOtherAction','save and next')
     );

     $form = new Form($this, __FUNCTION__, $fields, $actions);
     $form->loadDataFrom(Member::get()->byID(Member::currentUserID()));
     return $form;

}

public function myAction($data, $form) {
      $member = Member::get()->byId(Member::currentUserID());
      $form->saveInto($member);
      $member->write();      
}
```

I also had to add the canView, canEdit, canCreate and canDelete function to the Qualification DataObject to allow to edit and show it.