# Sending multi-dimensional array by POST

Tags: php, post, multidimensional-array

I am sending a multidimensional array by POST using the following:

```
<form action="fixtures.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?= $day ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?= $month ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?= $year ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="league" value="<?= $league ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="addFixtures" value="1">

    <?php

    for($i = 0; $i < count($fixtures); $i++){

         $team_a_name = $fixtures[$i]['team-a-name'];
         $team_b_name = $fixtures[$i]['team-b-name'];
         $fixtDate = $fixtures[$i]['Date'];

         echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i]['team-a-name']\" value='$team_a_name'>";
         echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i]['team-b-name']\" value='$team_b_name'>";
         echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i]['date']\" value='$fixtDate'>";

    }

    ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Add Fixtures">

</form>
```

However, when I try to access the values stored inside `$_POST['fixtures']`, using the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['addFixtures'])){

    print_r($_POST['fixtures'][0]);
    echo "<br><br>";
    print($_POST['fixtures'][0]['date']);

    exit;

}
```

I get this output:

> Array ( ['team-a-name'] => TEAM A ['team-b-name'] => TEAM B ['date'] => 5-4-2016 )
>
> Notice: Undefined index: date in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/soccerdome/fixtures.php on line
>   33

The same notice appears if I try to access 'team-a-name' or 'team-b-name'.
Why can't I access these values, when `print_r` on `$_POST['fixtures'][0]` clearly shows that they are in the array!

**EDIT**

When printing out `$_POST[]`, I get:

```
    Array
(
    [day] => 5
    [month] => 4
    [year] => 2016
    [league] => prem
    [addFixtures] => 1
    [fixtures] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['team-a-name'] => TEAM A
                    ['team-b-name'] => TEAM B
                    ['date'] => 5-4-2016
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ['team-a-name'] => TEAM C
                    ['team-b-name'] => TEAM D
                    ['date'] => 5-4-2016
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    ['team-a-name'] => TEAM A
                    ['team-b-name'] => TEAM D
                    ['date'] => 12-4-2016
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    ['team-a-name'] => TEAM B
                    ['team-b-name'] => TEAM C
                    ['date'] => 12-4-2016
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    ['team-a-name'] => TEAM A
                    ['team-b-name'] => TEAM C
                    ['date'] => 19-4-2016
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    ['team-a-name'] => TEAM D
                    ['team-b-name'] => TEAM B
                    ['date'] => 19-4-2016
                )

        )

)
```

**EDIT 2**

For some reason it is now working! I have no idea how, just be refreshing the page multiple times, the error message disappeared and the value inside POST was printed!

Comment: Here you are using capital 'D' in your date `$fixtDate = $fixtures[$i]['Date'];` and using 'date' in input name

Comment: Try removing the single quote from the key name in form input. Change name=\"fixtures[$i]['team-a-name']\" to name=\"fixtures[$i][team-a-name]\"

Comment: remove quotes like this:- `echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i][team-a-name]\" value='$team_a_name'>";
        `

Comment: @GhulamAli Then how `team-a-name` works?

Comment: You mean how to use in php? Just like what you were doing before echo $_POST['fixtures'][0]['date']; or echo $_POST['fixtures'][0]['team-a-name'];

Comment: single quotes are part of array name, so either remove them or use `echo $_POST['fixtures'][0]['\'date\'']`.

Comment: Check this link you may get some idea.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2433843/4912315

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have tried removing the quotes and the same error is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have any special characters in `date`, it is better to give without a `'`:

```
 echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i]['team-a-name']\" value='$team_a_name'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i]['team-b-name']\" value='$team_b_name'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i][date]\" value='$fixtDate'>";
```

Or change it to:

```
 echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i][team-a-name]\" value='$team_a_name'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i][team-b-name]\" value='$team_b_name'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"fixtures[$i][date]\" value='$fixtDate'>";
```

Always use `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` to check what's happening in reality. `:)`

Comment: I have put the output when using `print_r($_POST)` in my original question, but this code I have tried and it doesnt work

Comment: @sam Looks perfect for me.

Comment: Saying as I tried removing the quotes last, I'll mark your answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to traverse the post data is using `foreach`. You can do this as following:

```
if(isset($_POST['addFixtures']))
{
    foreach($_POST['fixtures'] as $key=>$value)
    {
      echo "<br><br>";
      print($value['date']);
    }
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

print_r the whole post array.i.e.print_r($_POST).Then you will have the exact keys and values assigned and will be successful in displaying the array.