# PHP - Spacing out Array Iterations

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv

I have multidimensional arrays that are generated by dynamic form inputs that a user can add to add things like awards, jobs and education.

When I collect the array data to push it to the .csv  it prints the array groupings like this `FinanceWaterlooTheodore2015TreasurerTorontoGary2014`.

Is it possible to mark a point where the array loop ends so it can be more legible and come out more like this FinanceWaterlooTheodore2015//TreasurerTorontoGary2014?

```
$unitLevelInvolvement = $_POST["unitLevelInvolvement"];

$unitInvolvementValue = "";
$i;
foreach($unitLevelInvolvement as $involvement)
{
    $i++;
    $unitInvolvementValue .= $involvement;
}
echo $unitInvolvementValue;

    <div name="unitLevelInvolvement" id="unitLevelInvolvement">
        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement[]" placeholder="Position/Committee" onBlur="this.placeholder='Position/Committee'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement[]" id="oectaUnit_1" placeholder="Unit" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />

        <div class="clearFix"></div>

        <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement[]" id="unitPresident_1" placeholder="Unit President" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit President'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
        <input type="date" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement[]" id="unitYear_1" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
        <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addUnitInvolvement()" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of unit-level-involvement div-->
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form><!--endForm-->
```

Comment: Could you not just do: $unitInvolvementValue .= "//$involvement";

Comment: Nope because that will arrange like thus finance//waterloo//theodore//2015//treasurer rather than what I need

Comment: `$unitInvolvementValue .= "//" . $involvement;` should work, although there's no reason to assign the values to a new variable just to echo it. You could just put `echo $involvement . "//";` in the foreach loop.

Comment: I tried that but what it does it put // between every value.  What I need are the value groups to have slashes between them so (FinanceWaterlooTheodore2015)//(TreasurerTorontoGary2014) So loop 1 collects the first set, puts a break and then loop two will collect the second set.

Comment: isn't better to use a comma instead of slash as a delimiter?

Comment: Commas are great.  But please read the question.  I need to collect the groups of array iterations, mark an end and collect the next loop and then print.

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner The problem is you're not distinguishing between "groups" in your HTML. You're adding everything to `unitLevelInvolvement` array indiscriminately. The PHP code has no way of knowing when one group ends and another begins.

Comment: How would I go about amending that or marking a clear delineation?

Comment: @stephenWidom Can you help me with this or set me on the right track

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are trying to put the separator every 4 iterations (because you have 4 inputs).

**Note** that this answer will only work if you have exactly 4 inputs.

You could try something like this:

```
$unitLevelInvolvement = $_POST["unitLevelInvolvement"];

$unitInvolvementValue = "";
$i = 0;
foreach($unitLevelInvolvement as $involvement)
    {
        $unitInvolvementValue .= $involvement;
        $i++;
        if($i % 4 == 0){
          $unitInvolvementValue .= "//";
        }
    }
echo $unitInvolvementValue;
```

Comment: If OP (or a nefarious user) adds/removes a field, his data would be corrupted. OP has to create a new array for each group in his form HTML.

Comment: @stephenWidom Can you help me with this or set me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create "groups" since you don't have any yet. You can do this by creating a multidimensional array with the `name` attribute. Your HTML could look something like this:

```
<div name="unitLevelInvolvement" id="unitLevelInvolvement">
    <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement['group1'][]" placeholder="Position/Committee" onBlur="this.placeholder='Position/Committee'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
    <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement['group1'][]" id="oectaUnit_1" placeholder="Unit" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />

    <div class="clearFix"></div>

    <input type="text" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement['group2'][]" id="unitPresident_1" placeholder="Unit President" onBlur="this.placeholder='Unit President'" onFocus="this.placeholder=''" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
    <input type="date" class="two-lines-textbox" name="unitLevelInvolvement['group2'][]" id="unitYear_1" onKeyUp="checkPage3()" />
    <input type="button" value="+" onClick="addUnitInvolvement()" />
    </div>
</div><!-- end of unit-level-involvement div-->
```

You can then iterate over the array like this:

```
$unitInvolvementValue = array();
foreach($unitLevelInvolvement as $group)
{
    $groupInvolvement = "";
    foreach($group as $involvement)
    {
        $groupInvolvement .= $involvement;
    }
    $unitInvolvementValue[] = $groupInvolvement;
}

echo implode("//", $unitInvolvementValue );
```

I'm using the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) approach because it adds the separator only between the values and not at the beginning or the end of the string.