# submitting an array with loop and variables in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

My problem is similar to [Submitting a multidimensional array via POST with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php)

The only difference is, that my data are generated from a csv file:

```
<?php
$fileHandle = fopen("data/group.csv", "r");

 while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<label for="id">' . $row[0] . '</label>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<label for="description">' . $row[1] . '</label>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td valign="top">';
    echo '<label for="diameter">' . $row[2] . '</label>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $row[0] . '" value="' . $row[3] . '" checked="checked">' . $row[3] . ' pcs';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $row[0] . '" value="' . $row[4] . '">' . $row[4] . ' pcs';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $row[0] . '" value="' . $row[5] . '">' . $row[5] . ' pcs';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

To review this before sending, I am using the following code which works just fine:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';

foreach ($_POST as $id => $amount) {
  if ($amount <> 0) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';    
    echo '<label for="id">' . $id . '</label>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<label for="amount">' . $amount . ' pcs</label>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
?>
```

and the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [5465653] => 0
    [81613] => 0
    [21318] => 400
    [348787] => 400
    [663] => 800
)
```

so the formated output is for example

```
id      amount
21318   400 pcs.
348787  400 pcs.
663     800 pcs.
```

The problem is, however, I can't get the other rows (description and diameter) into review page, so the output looks like this:

```
id      description   diameter    amount
21318   Description   10          400 pcs.
348787  Description   10          400 pcs.
663     Description   15          800 pcs.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you are just getting last row data in post?

Comment: Well if you want to send those values from one page to the next, you need to add form fields containing them as well.

Comment: Hi Amit, no. I am getting correct data: id from row[0] and value from row[3], [4] or [5] (whatever selected). Row[1] and [2] are the ones I need to be returned as well.

Comment: then what's the issue and what is your actual requirement?