# Catch array of HTML multiple select with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html-select, multi-select

I have two multiple selects declared as:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="vcgame[]" id="vcgame_1" value="">
  <select name="vccoun[][]" id="vccoun_5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">West Indies</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">India</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Australia</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="vcgame[]" id="vcgame_2" value="">
  <select name="vccoun[][]" id="vccoun_9" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="4">Italy</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Germany</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I want to catch the values in PHP,  like this

```
$game_list= $_POST['vcgame'];
$country_list= $_POST['vccoun'];
$game_country= array();
foreach($game_list as $key=>$val)
{
    $game_country[$key]= $country_list[$key];
}
```

But the values come like this (with `print_r` on the `$_POST`):

```
[vcgame] => Array
(
    [0] => cricket
    [1] => football
)

[vccoun] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
    )
)
```

instead of:

```
[vcgame] => Array
(
    [0] => cricket
    [1] => football
)

[vccoun] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )
)
```

How can this be achieved? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values you are expecting?

Comment: [vccoun]= array(array(2,3), array(5))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submitting a multidimensional array via POST with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433727/submitting-a-multidimensional-array-via-post-with-php)

Comment: checking and let you know

Comment: Not sure but you may want to do selects like this for a better array structure:  `name="vccoun[cricket][]"` and `name="vccoun[football][]"`. Then you won't need hidden inputs.

Comment: Yes. This will do. But if the input type is 'text' (not 'hidden'), what will be the logic? But a good point. I'm editing the question accordingly.

Comment: @ArSeN these blocks are generate by ajax calls and each block can be removed (with a button). So no specific indexing is not possible. I need some generic solution.

Comment: Making select single (instead of multiple) will work at once.

Comment: `no specific indexing is not possible` why not? You can dynamically index it depending on the added sports, e.g. with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the names of the fields on the form to the indices at which you want the desired result:

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="vcgame[0]" id="vcgame_1" value="">
  <select name="vccoun[0][]" id="vccoun_5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">West Indies</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">India</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Australia</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="vcgame[1]" id="vcgame_2" value="">
  <select name="vccoun[1][]" id="vccoun_9" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="4">Italy</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Germany</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Then `$_POST` output is:

```
Array
(
    [vcgame] => Array
        (
            [0] => cricket
            [1] => football
        )
    [vccoun] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 3
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )
        )
)
```

Or even like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="data[0][vcgame]" id="vcgame_1" value="">
<select name="data[0][vccoun][]" id="vccoun_5" multiple="multiple">
...
<input type="text" name="data[1][vcgame]" id="vcgame_2" value="">
<select name="data[1][vccoun][]" id="vccoun_9" multiple="multiple">
```

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [vcgame] => cricket
                    [vccoun] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 3
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [vcgame] => football
                    [vccoun] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: The second alternative is exactly what I wanted. Thanks...